# How VPN can affect the position of keywords in search engines?

Tags: seo, google, keywords, vpn

I am trying for a keyword in google. When I use VPN, the keyword positions well in google results but without using VPN, the results differs and the keyword position is not acceptable. Why the keyword position differs with or without using VPN?

Comment: See also: [How do you Google Search without personalization and localisation?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/13264/how-do-you-google-search-without-personalization-and-localisation)